# Nodemailer sendingRate works locally, but only sends the specified number of emails on Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda, nodemailer

My transporter is set-up as such:

```
 const ses = new aws.SES();
 var transporter = mailer.createTransport({ 
    SES: ses,
    sendingRate: 25
  });
```

I have a sendEmail function that sets up an email to send an attachment:

```
function sendEmail(body, filename, customer_name) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: "test@test.com",
    subject: "A test subject - " + customer_name,
    html: '<p>' + customer_name + '</p><br />Please see attached file.',
    to: "testing@testing.com",
    attachments: [
      {
          filename: filename + ".txt",
          content: body.toString()
      }
    ]
  };
  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```

Within the Lambda, I add the sendEmail to an array of promises and process as such:

```
module.exports.publish = async (event, context, callback) => {
...
var promises = data.map(async (i) => {
  ...
  await sendEmail(data, file_prefix, customer_name);
};
await Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
   addMessageToLog('Emails sent successfully');
});
await sendSNS(logger).then(() => {
   if (isError) { callback(errorObj); }
   callback(null, 'Emails successfully sent.');
});
```

My issue is that when I invoke this locally using the Serverless framework in VS Code, all my emails run perfectly fine at what seems like a 25/sec rate as specified. When I deploy to AWS Lambda, it simply sends 25 emails, then the request ends. Locally, it sends my SNS topic my log messages, but not on the Lambda. It abruptly ends at 25 every time.

Am I using the sendingRate correctly in this case? Why would the AWS Lambda end the request but not my test locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put this here for posterity in case anyone else runs into this...

I set the maxConnections to 1 and this fixed my issue on AWS.